# How to setup FCM in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I am new to `Xamarin`.
How to setup FCM in `Xamarin` forms for both environments (Android and iOS)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/firebase-cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find this GitHub source code for understanding cross-platform implementation of FCM in xamarin forms.

https://github.com/yamachu/TryFirebaseXamarin

Separately follow this source to understand the setup of FCM for:

- **android**

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1121218/Android-Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-Tutorial

- **iOS**

https://xamarinlatino.com/xamarin-forms-firebase-cloud-messaging-ios-setup-1961a91d4055