# Xamarin Form Notification with FireBase

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can any one tell me about xamarin form notification with firebase. I read out many blogs and tutorials, they are using xamarin.android. But i want to implement notification with xamarin form.
Can any one help me out of it or tell me the alternate.

Thanks

Comment: as @StevenThewissen said in his answer, you can find the tutorial on this site, but you still need to implement it inside the android project. There's no way (As I know) to implement it once in Xamarin.Forms yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup FCM in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163941/how-to-setup-fcm-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

There are more then enough resources online available to help you with this. The Microsoft website has a tutorial that uses Notification Hubs (which is a feature of Azure). This connects to both FireBase for Android and APNS for iOS devices. Their tutorial to implement this can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push